# How to check if specified tag is inside in rad editor content

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using Telerik Rad editor. using vs 2010 with c#.

I bind the content to editor during page load.

On button click event ,i need to check if th particular tag (for ex: ) is inside the content in HTML mode.

I am using the following code.

```
    if (Radeditor1.Content.Contains("<title/>"))
    { 

    }
```

Tag has value like welcome.

so Content .contains take it like as a string and return false.

How to check it.

Thanks and Regards,
Pooja

Answer (score 1):

I could be seeing it wrong but if you just want to find the start of the tag you could use:

```
if (Radeditor1.Content.Contains("<title"))
{ 

}
```

If you want to retrieve  the contents of the tag you could use Regex like so

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(Radeditor1.Content, @"\<title[^\<]*\>(?<content>.*?)\<\/title\>", RegexOptions.Multiline);
if (match.Success)
{
     string content = match.Groups["content"].Value;
}
```

Comment: No, my content value like this. <preparation-group id="bnf_64864_preparation-group_1" name="candesartancilexetil">
    <h2>candesartancilexetil</h2>
    <body />
    <preparation id="bnf_64866" name="Amias®">
      <h3>Amias®</h3>
    </preparation>
  </preparation-group>

Comment: maybe you could post up the exact contents for Radeditor1.Content and the exact string you would like to check for/ retrieve from Radeditor1.Content